# How do I match numbers after a particular string without a positive lookbehind?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regex-group, re2

```
Target file 39: Assignment4/Assignment4-sa471 - Sarah Iwobi.pde
```

I am attempting to match the numbers `471` after `sa` in the string above. This is possible using a positive lookahead in Python: `(?<=sa)[0-9]+`. Unfortunately, this is not possible in Google Sheets.

I attempted to use the regex expression `[sa][0-9]+` but it includes the letter a in addition to the numbers: `a471`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "sa(\d+)")
```

Here, `sa` will be matched, and one or more digits after the substring will be matched and captured into Group 1.

The `REGEXEXTRACT` function will return the *captured* value if a capturing group is defined in the regex pattern.

See the [RE2 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3wrf5e/1).

Comment: @Mandy8055 Both use RE2 regex library.